# Kentico 10: Custom modules, unigrid, and more

Tags: c#, asp.net, customization, kentico

I am trying to develop a custom module using Kentico best practices where possible. I have been following the article at https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/creating-custom-modules, however I have found little direction when it comes to the following:

1 - When dealing with a custom UniGrid, I have had no luck passing a parameter with the EditActionUrl. From my understanding, the first column declared in the Columns property should be the 0-indexed string format parameter, however my EditActionUrl of "~/CMSModules/VendorOrders/EditVendorOrder.aspx?VendorID={0}" always takes the '{0}' as a literal. The only way I have gotten this to work is to create a custom OnAction handler with a Response.Redirect() to the appropriate editor page, but this doesn't feel best practice to me. Here is my relevant source:

ASPX:

```
<cms:UniGrid ID="gridCurrentOrders" runat="server" OrderBy="Name" 
    Columns="VendorID,Name,ItemCount,TotalQuantity,TotalCost"
    EditActionUrl="~/CMSModules/VendorOrders/EditVendorOrder.aspx?VendorID={0}">
    <GridActions Width="50">
        <ug:Action Name="edit" Caption="$General.Edit$" FontIconClass="icon-edit" FontIconStyle="allow" />
    </GridActions>
    <GridColumns>
        <ug:Column source="Name" caption="Vendor" width="50"></ug:Column>
        <ug:Column source="ItemCount" caption="Item Count" width="25"></ug:Column>
        <ug:Column source="TotalQuantity" caption="Total Qty" width="25"></ug:Column>
        <ug:Column source="TotalCost" caption="Item Cost" width="100%"></ug:Column>
    </GridColumns>
</cms:UniGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Calculate which SKUs need to be reordered as follows:
    // When [AvailableItems] + [Amount unshipped already on an open vendor order] is at or less than [ReorderAt], reorder [ReorderQuantity]
    gridCurrentOrders.DataSource = SKUInfoProvider.GetSKUs()
        .Source(sku => sku.Join<VendorInfo>("SKUVendorID", "VendorID"))
        .Where("SKUAvailableItems <= SKUReorderAt")
        .GroupBy("VendorID", "Name")
        .Columns("VendorID, Name, count(SKUID) as ItemCount, sum(SKUReorderQuantity) as TotalQuantity, sum(SKUVendorCost * SKUReorderQuantity) as TotalCost")
        .Result;
 }
```

2 - When using the built-in templates for a Custom Module UI page, you can simply check the "Display Breadcrumbs" box, however for seemingly obvious reasons, this doesn't do anything when Type = "URL". Is there a standard way to wire up breadcrumbs on custom .aspx module pages?

TIA, -Keith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create OnAction handler

```
protected void gridElem_OnAction(string actionName, object actionArgument)
{
    if (actionName == "edit")
    {
        URLHelper.Redirect(UrlResolver.ResolveUrl("/CMSModules/VendorOrders/EditVendorOrder.aspx?VendorID=" + Convert.ToString(actionArgument)));
    }
}
```

to your second problem you can do it manually by adding Attributes to class of the page, like in the following screenshot
[image]

Comment: I tried the following with no luck.  What am I missing?

`[UIElement("VendorOrder", "EditVendorOrder")]
    [Breadcrumbs]
    [Breadcrumb(0, TargetUrl = "~/CMSModules/VendorOrders/VendorOrderList.aspx", Text = "Vendor Orders")]
    [Breadcrumb(1, Text = "Edit Vendor Order", ExistingObject = true)]
    [Breadcrumb(1, Text = "Edit Vendor Order", NewObject = true)]
    [EditedObject(VendorOrderInfo.OBJECT_TYPE, "VendorOrderID")]
    [Title(Text = "Edit Vendor Order", ExistingObject = true)]
    [Title(Text = "Edit Vendor Order", NewObject = true)]`

Comment: The only difference I have found is that I'm inheriting directly from CMSPage, while the examples I have found using this attribute inherit from CMSContentPage (which eventually inherits from CMSPage).

Comment: Just to throw another wrench in this, if I look at Currency_Edit.aspx, it appears as though they are trying to set the parent breadcrumb as Currency_List.aspx, however when I visit the page in the dashboard, the breadcrumb just shows "Multistore Configuration => US Dollar", even though the resource says it should say "Currencies".  It seems like breadcrumbs don't exactly work the way I would expect them to.